# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x^2+1)}\sin(ax)dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x^2+1)}\sin(ax)dx$$
My try:

$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}e^{iax}$ and then I thought using semi-circle on the imaginary axis and taking the imaginary part of the integral but when i take the imaginary i don't get the same function.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Try  rectangular region with one side on the real axis ($-a<x <b$, $a,b>0$) two verticalblines going op from $x=-a$ and $x=b$ at a hight $c>a,b$.  This is a typical counter for Fourier transforms of functions that are holomorphic on the region containing the upper half space whiteout poles on the real axis, as is your case. Here you will also take limits as $a,b\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: we didn't learn Fourier transforms only thre Residue Theorem

Comment: Let's not make reference to Fourer transform then, it seems you are aversed to things you don't see in class. In any case, the countour I am suggesting should work, it is a typical example.

Comment: Using the counter I suggested, you will arrive at the formula given below by José Carlos Santos's. See Marsden's basic complex analysis (just to mention one) where they discuss the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proved in Complex Analysis textbooks that if $A$ is a finite subset of $\Bbb C$ and if $f\colon\Bbb C\setminus A\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is analytic and $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$, then$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)e^{iaz}\,\mathrm dz=\begin{cases}\displaystyle2\pi i\sum_{w\in A,\ \operatorname{Im}w>0}\operatorname{res}(w,f(z)e^{iaz})&\text{ if }a>0\\-2\pi i\displaystyle\sum_{w\in A,\ \operatorname{Im}w<0}\operatorname{res}(w,f(z)e^{iaz})&\text{ if }a>0\end{cases}.$$So,\begin{align*}\int_0^\infty\frac x{x^2+1}\sin(ax)\,\mathrm dx&=\frac12\operatorname{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{iax}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\right)\\&=\begin{cases}\pi e^{-a}&\text{ if }a>0\\-\pi e^a&\text{ if }a<0.\end{cases}\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Let $I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x(x^2+1)}dx$. Then,

$$I’’(a) =- \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin ax}{x^2+1}dx
= I(a) -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx= I(a)- \frac\pi2
$$

which leads to $I(a)= \frac{\pi a}{2|a|}(1-e^{-|a|})$. Thus,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin ax }{x^2+1}dx
= -2I’’(a)= \frac{\pi a}{|a|}e^{-|a|}
$$

Comment: can you expand you explanation?